App Route with two parameters quit working with updated dependencies
I recently updated to a new version of flask/python/google app engine. I have the controller below.
@app.route('/area/entity/<int:video_id>/subentity/<int:collection_id>/', methods=['POST'])
def entity_subentiy_associate_collection(video_id, collection_id):


This has quit working, can I ask for assistance. Did something change? Should I expect this route path to work with flask=2.2.5

"Quit working" is ambiguous. What exactly happens? What version of gcloud SDK are you on (asking because you said you updated to a new version of GAE)

can you check your route definition def entity\_subentiy\_associate\_collection is this parameter subentity is misspelled? If it is correct the spelling of subentiy to subentity in your route definition and see

@NoCommandLine to remove ambiguity, the path quit routing. removing the explicit int: reconnected the path.  I'm suspecting a python 3 change

I believe it should be
'/area/entity/<video_id:int>/subentity/<collection_id:int>/', 

Note the ordering - the type hint comes after the variable name. See this and this
